# Racket FFI: C function which accepts a pointer to a function

Tags: racket, ffi

I'd like to bind to a C function `abc` whose signature is:

```
int abc(void (*)(int))
```

I.e. it accepts a pointer to a function. This callback accepts an `int` and has `void` return type.

What's the right incantation in Racket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example for a similar binding: let's say that we want to bind a function `callTwice` with the signature:

```
int callTwice(int (*)(int));
```

and with the silly C implementation:

```
int callTwice(int (*f)(int)) {
  return f(f(42));
}
```

Here's what the Racket FFI binding looks like:

```
(define call-twice (get-ffi-obj "callTwice" the-lib
                                (_fun (_fun _int -> _int) -> _int)))
```

where `the-lib` is the FFI-bound library we get from [`ffi-lib`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/Loading_Foreign_Libraries.html#%28def._%28%28lib._ffi/unsafe..rkt%29._ffi-lib%29%29).  Here, we see that the first argument to `call-twice` is itself a `(_fun _int -> _int)`, which is the function pointer type we want for my example.

That means that technically we could have written this:

```
(define _mycallback (_fun _int -> _int))

(define call-twice (get-ffi-obj "callTwice" the-lib
                                (_fun _mycallback -> _int)))
```

to make it easier to see that `call-twice` takes in a callback as its only argument.  For your case, you'll probably want `(_fun _int -> _void)` for the value of your callback type.

The fully worked-out example can be found here: https://github.com/dyoo/ffi-tutorial/tree/master/ffi/tutorial/examples/call-twice.  Run the `pre-installer.rkt` in that directory to build the extension, and then test it out by running `test-call-twice.rkt`.

Comment: See also the [tests](http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/blob/HEAD:/collects/tests/racket/foreign-test.rktl) (look for `'ho`) and [the C code](http://git.racket-lang.org/plt/blob/HEAD:/collects/tests/racket/foreign-test.c) they're running on.